# Talking to Unknown IP device

Tags: shell, serial-port, tcpip

I want to communicate with time attendance device for reading stored time and have the following concerns:

Is there any workaround to discover connection port or type?

Is there any specific communication shell or programming language for such devices like AT commands for modems and if so, does any development environment exists for such devices?

Is it possible to simulate serial data stream through TCP/IP?

Is it possible to directly read memory behind its interface or write directly to its memory?

The device is IP based and original software setting uses COM1 port. My understanding is that tc400.dll miflink.dll mormam.dll mtmlink.dll borlndmm.dll may be used when communication occurs.

Comment: You need to provide more information about your device. If it is totally alien, provide an image.

Comment: There certainly exist serial port emulators with TCP support, question is whether your new device actually speaks the same protocol...

Comment: nmap result as follow:

Comment: MAC Address: 00:60:35:07:C0:BA (Dallas Semiconductor)
Device type: router|switch|power-device|general purpose|webcam|printer
Running: Allied Telesis AlliedWare, Allied Telesyn AlliedWare, Allied Telesyn embedded, Generex embedded, Microsoft Windows XP, Polycom embedded, Samsung embedded

OS CPE: cpe:/o:alliedtelesis:alliedware:54291-05 cpe:/h:alliedtelesyn:at-ar300l cpe:/o:alliedtelesyn:alliedware cpe:/h:alliedtelesyn:rapier_24i cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_xp::sp3 cpe:/h:polycom:viewstation_4000 cpe:/h:samsung:clx-3185fw
Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details

Comment: @hussein5, please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1288174/edit) the info from your comment into your question and format as `code sample` using backticks or indentation (4 spaces)

Answer (score 0):

> **I want to communicate with time attendance device**

The appropriate approach is to contact the manufacturer of the specific device and ask if they provide a published 3rd-party API for their device and have a developer support program.

> **Is there any workaround to discover connection port or type?**

A typical tool is [nmap](https://nmap.org/) - the free network-mapper. There are other tools. Don't use this on any network you do not own or for which you have not obtained explicit permission to map (ideally in writing). People who misuse these tools in a corporate network without permission often end up with a criminal record.

> **Is there any specific communication shell or programming language for such devices like AT commands for modems**

There is no globally accepted defacto or dejure standard specifically for time-attendance devices AFAIK.

> **Is it possible to simulate serial data stream through TCP/IP?**

Yes, that is commonplace and there are several protocols defined for this purpose. For example [Telnet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854) essentially replaced RS232 serial communications. SSH has essentially replaced Telnet. There are many other similar bidirectional character and line oriented protocols and examples of simple two-way direct TCP connections. Many if not most Internet protocols are built on top of simple bidirectional TCP connections that operate somewhat like a RS232 serial connection. The main differences are the lack of separate control-lines for things like flow-control and endpoint status - separate from the main data stream.

There also exist (well, used to exist) hardware devices that allow you to connect serial devices to a TCP/IP network. There were often called terminal-servers.

> **Is it possible to directly read memory behind its interface or write directly to its memory?**

That depends entirely on what facilities the specific device has been explicitly designed to provide. You don't mention a specific device so the general answer is "mostly not".

Comment: to : RedGrittyBrick     i got my answer. but my additional question is that is there any generic terminal emulator or reference to learn data streaming to and from rs232 ?  whether a flash drive or USB keyboard or network card uses the same steaming protocol ?

Comment: @hussein5 you should ask that using the "[ask question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask)" link above, but no, USB serial is different and thousands of times more complex than RS232 serial. There's very very little in common. If any answer is useful, consider upvoting it.